# Create a "Yes/No" drop down list via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I wrote a script to create a yes/no drop-down list. However, in the few tries at first, it worked perfectly. However, later on, there's an error message "Run time error 1004: Select method of Range class failed"

```
Sub Drop_Down_List()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M2:N2851").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Yes,No"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: [There is no need to Select here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Change `With Selection.Validation` to `With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M2:N2851").Validation`.

Comment: Is the sheet in discussion protected (now)?

Comment: Ah yes, the sheet is protected, but I have a script that allows macros: Worksheets.Protect Password:="ABC123", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

Comment: There are some things that you can't change on a protected sheet via code, even with  UserInterfaceOnly:=True. (don't know if this is documented somewhere). You will have to unprotect the sheet first.

Comment: You can't select a range n a sheet if that sheet is not active

Comment: May I ask, is there a way that makes macro buttons, autofilter work in a protected sheet?